# Get pager working in a tab control

Tags: xpages

I have amended and XPage to have it expanded to have a tab control (2 tabs) and included a pager in one tab (the first tab\default tab).  The pager is bound to a dynamicviewpanel using the "for" property.  I have used dynamicviewpanels with pagers before with no issues, but when I click on the "next" or "2" icon to move forward a page it does not move page and the only change is the first tab vanishes and the 2nd tab is shown but the page still shows the first tabs data.  How do I resolve this please?  I thought it may require a full refresh put there is only a partial refresh

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have this resolved.  I just changed the pagers "partialRefresh" property to False.  There is another component on the page that performs a refresh of the page anyway